# Props is updating before useEffect side effect

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component which shows a question, there's a button within it that allows you to reveal the answer, this is handled through the `revealedResults` property/state.

```
const Question = ({
  item
}: {
  item: QuestionType;
}) => {
  const [revealedResults, setRevealedResults] = useState(false);
  const { question, answers } = item;

  useEffect(() => {
    setRevealedResults(false);
  }, [item]);

  const handleResultReveal = () => {
    setRevealedResults(true);
  };


  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Question: {question}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handleResultReveal()}>Reveal Answer</button>
      <div>
        {revealedResults && answers.map((answer) => <p>{answer}</p>)}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Question;



const Questionaire = () => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState(questions[0]);
  const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = useState(0);
  const [incorrectAnswers, setIncorrectAnswers] = useState(0);

  const handleQuestionAnswer = (isCorrect: boolean): void => {
    if (isCorrect) {
      setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers + 1);
    } else {
      setIncorrectAnswers(incorrectAnswers + 1);
    }

    setQuestion(questions[1]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Question item={question} />

      <section>
        <div>
          <p> Did you get the answer correct?</p>
          <button onClick={() => handleQuestionAnswer(true)}>Yes</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleQuestionAnswer(false)}>No</button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Questionaire;
```

The question updates through the `item` prop. The idea is that when the `item` prop updates `setRevealedResults` is ran again to hide the revealed result of the next question.

The problem I'm having is that the prop of the new question is being flashed right before the useEffect side effect is being ran. You can see this here:

[image: flashing text]

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: what does your calling component look like?

Comment: Show your logic for `Yes` button.

Comment: updated  the original post

Comment: you start of initializing `useState(question[0]` & then set to `setQuestion(questions[1]);` in the `handleQuestionAnswer ` so it first renders the question you have in state. So, what you do in `handleQuestionAnswer `  you'll want to do earlier. How does the component that calls `Questionaire ` look like?

Comment: `Questionaire` is the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect runs after the render is done. That's why you see the page change for a moment there.
Try to use useMemo instead. It should update during the render.